# Difference in boost::asio::io_service behaviour between GCC and MSVC: cannot cancel posted jobs

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, boost-asio, threadpool

When implementing a basic thread pool using `boost::asio::io_service`, I am observing some differences in how queued tasks are handled when stopping the `io_service`.

On MSVC 14 (MS Visual Studio 2015), for some reason the queued tasks which were not started yet are not dropped when stopping the `io_service` but are run nonetheless. These tasks are dropped when running this on Ubuntu 16.04 (GCC 5.4.0).

I have simplified and cleaned up the original tests and put them in a [single file](https://svn.boost.org/trac10/attachment/ticket/13317/ThreadPoolTests.cpp) (also listed below) which only depends on boost and uses some sleeps to demonstrate the problem. You can build it with the [`CMakeLists.txt`](https://svn.boost.org/trac10/attachment/ticket/13317/CMakeLists.txt) (also listed below) if you wish or use the online compilers linked below.
*Notice that the thread pool uses only one worker thread so that the jobs are run sequentially.*

The output with GCC is as expected ([Here on an online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CY4onVi1ktxSzUGR)):

```
 checkAllWorkIsProcessedBeforeDestruction  
     passed.  
     passed.  
     passed.  
checkWorkCanBeCancelled
     passed.
     passed.
     passed.
checkWorkCanBeInterrupted
     passed.
     passed.
     passed.
checkUninterruptableWorkIsNotInterruptedButCanBeDropped
     passed.
     passed.
     passed.
     passed.
```

This is the output on MSVC 14 (Visual Studio 2015) ([Here on an online VC++ compiler](http://rextester.com/ZNHVP40490)):

```
checkAllWorkIsProcessedBeforeDestruction
     passed.
     passed.
     passed.
checkWorkCanBeCancelled
     Error: functor 1 call expected: false current: true
     Error: functor 2 call expected: false current: true
     Error: running time expected: 150 current: 402
checkWorkCanBeInterrupted
     passed.
     passed.
     passed.
checkUninterruptableWorkIsNotInterruptedButCanBeDropped
     passed.
     Error: functor 2 call expected: false current: true
     passed.
     Error: running time expected: 250 current: 404
```

**Am I doing something wrong?**

I have also filled a bug to boost but got no response so far: [#13317](https://svn.boost.org/trac10/ticket/13317)

---

Source code: `ThreadPoolTests.cpp`

```
// Copyright (c) 2017 Diego Barrios Romero <eldruin@gmail.com>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>

class ThreadPool
{
public:
  ThreadPool(const size_t threadCount = boost::thread::hardware_concurrency())
    : work(new boost::asio::io_service::work(service))
  {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < threadCount; ++i)
    {
      threads.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &service));
    }
  }
  template<typename FunctionType>
  void post(FunctionType f)
  {
    service.post(f);
  }

  void interrupt()
  {
    threads.interrupt_all();
  }

  void cancel()
  {
    work.reset();
    service.stop();
  }

  ~ThreadPool()
  {
    work.reset();
    threads.join_all();
  }
private:
  boost::asio::io_service service;
  boost::thread_group threads;
  std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> work;
};


struct Functor
{
  void operator()()
  {
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(200));
    boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(mutex);
    wasCalled_ = true;
  }
  bool wasCalled() const
  {
    boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(mutex);
    return wasCalled_;
  }

private:
  bool wasCalled_ = false;
  mutable boost::mutex mutex;
};

struct UninterruptableFunctor : public Functor
{
  void operator()()
  {
    boost::this_thread::disable_interruption disableInterruptions;
    Functor::operator()();
  }
};

template<typename F, typename T1, typename T2>
void check(F compare, T1 expected, T2 current, const std::string& msg)
{
  if (compare(expected, current))
  {
    std::cout << "\tpassed." << std::endl;
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
              << "\tError: " << msg << " expected: " << expected
              << " current: " << current << std::endl;
  }
}

struct ThreadPoolTest
{
  boost::int_least64_t getRunningTimeInMS() const
  {
    auto executionTime = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start;
    return boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::milliseconds>(executionTime).count();    
  }

  template<typename FunctorType, typename F>
  void runTest(F f, bool shouldFunctor1BeCalled, bool shouldFunctor2BeCalled)
  {
    FunctorType functor1, functor2;
    {
      ThreadPool pool(1);
      pool.post(boost::bind(&FunctorType::operator(), &functor1));
      pool.post(boost::bind(&FunctorType::operator(), &functor2));
      f(pool);
    }

    auto eq = [](bool a, bool b) { return a == b; };
    check(eq, shouldFunctor1BeCalled, functor1.wasCalled(), "functor 1 call");
    check(eq, shouldFunctor2BeCalled, functor2.wasCalled(), "functor 2 call");
  }

private:
  boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point start = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
};

void doNothing(ThreadPool&) { }
void cancel(ThreadPool& pool)
{
  pool.cancel();
}
void waitForStartThenInterruptThenCancel(ThreadPool& pool)
{
  boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(100));
  pool.interrupt();
  pool.cancel();
}

bool lessEq (const boost::int_least64_t a, const boost::int_least64_t b) { return a <= b; }
bool greaterEq (const boost::int_least64_t a, const boost::int_least64_t b) { return a >= b; }

void checkAllWorkIsProcessedBeforeDestruction()
{
  ThreadPoolTest test;
  std::cout << "checkAllWorkIsProcessedBeforeDestruction\n";
  test.runTest<Functor>(doNothing, true, true);
  check(lessEq, 350, test.getRunningTimeInMS(), "running time");
}

void checkWorkCanBeCancelled()
{
  ThreadPoolTest test;
  std::cout << "checkWorkCanBeCancelled\n";
  test.runTest<Functor>(cancel, false, false);
  check(greaterEq, 150, test.getRunningTimeInMS(), "running time");
}

void checkWorkCanBeInterrupted()
{
  ThreadPoolTest test;
  std::cout << "checkWorkCanBeInterrupted\n";
  test.runTest<Functor>(waitForStartThenInterruptThenCancel, false, false);
  check(greaterEq, 150, test.getRunningTimeInMS(), "running time");
}

void checkUninterruptableWorkIsNotInterruptedButCanBeDropped()
{
  ThreadPoolTest test;
  std::cout << "checkUninterruptableWorkIsNotInterruptedButCanBeDropped\n";
  test.runTest<UninterruptableFunctor>(waitForStartThenInterruptThenCancel, true, false);
  check(lessEq, 150, test.getRunningTimeInMS(), "running time");
  check(greaterEq, 250, test.getRunningTimeInMS(), "running time");
}

int main(int, char*[])
{
  checkAllWorkIsProcessedBeforeDestruction();
  checkWorkCanBeCancelled();
  checkWorkCanBeInterrupted();
  checkUninterruptableWorkIsNotInterruptedButCanBeDropped();
}
```

Here the `CMakeLists.txt` for compilation ease.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8.11)
project (ThreadPoolTests)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS thread)
if (Boost_FOUND)
  include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
else()
  message(FATAL_ERROR "No Boost found")
endif()

add_executable (ThreadPoolTests ThreadPoolTests.cpp)
target_link_libraries(ThreadPoolTests ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

---

Again the question: **Am I doing something wrong?**

Comment: Is this the "wrong" output you get? http://rextester.com/ZNHVP40490

Comment: @sehe yes. I will add the link to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I saw a problem with your tests.

Let's start with that first.

### Cancel, Racy Tests

`ThreadPool::cancel` does two things:

- reset `work` (allowing `io_service::run()` to complete)
- `stop` the service

The problem is, resetting `work` doesn't affect any work already in progress. Neither does `stop`. So, any work already posted will be completed.

The only situation in which you get your "expected" behaviour is in the off chance that you `stop` the `io_service` even before the first thread in the pool started running one of the posted tasks.

The fact that you ***seem*** to get this behaviour on GCC consistently is a fluke. In reality it's a race, and that's easily demonstrated by adding the tiniest delay before `cancel()`.

In fact, even with the code as is, repeated runs showed spurious failures like:

```
checkWorkCanBeCancelled
    Error: functor 1 call expected: false actual: true
    passed (functor 2 call).
    Error: running time expected: 150 actual: 200
```

Enabling handler tracking confirms that only one handler was abandoned:

[image]

Even just enabling address sanitizer made the failure become pretty much always reproducible.

### Digging Deeper: `io_service::stop`

If it's a race, and the tests are limited to a single service thread, surely the subtle race window would not be large enough to allow the second task to run even though `io_service::stop()` had been called?

I struggled with this one, so I instrumented the `Functor` function with some more timing sampling. Let's also record the invocation of a task so we can distinguish tasks that were never started from those that merely didn't complete:

```
struct Functor {
    void operator()() {
        {
            boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(mutex);
            state_.invocation = Clock::now();
        }
        boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(200));
        {
            boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(mutex);
            state_.completion = Clock::now();
        }
    }

    struct State {
        TP start, invocation, completion;

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, State const& s) {
            return os << "[" << relative(s.invocation, s.start) << "," << relative(s.completion, s.start) << "]";
        }
    };

    State sample() const {
        boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(mutex);
        return state_;
    }

  private:
    State state_ = { TP::min(), TP::min(), TP::min() };
    mutable boost::mutex mutex;
};


struct Functor {
    void operator()() {
        {
            boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(mutex);
            state_.wasInvoked = true;
        }
        boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(200));
        {
            boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(mutex);
            state_.wasCompleted = true;
        }
    }

    struct State {
        bool wasInvoked, wasCompleted;

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, State const& s) {
            if (s.wasInvoked && s.wasCompleted) return os << "[invoked,completed]";
            if (s.wasInvoked) return os << "[invoked]";
            assert(!s.wasCompleted);
            return os << "[]";
        }
    };

    State sample() const {
        boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(mutex);
        return state_;
    }

  private:
    State state_ = { false, false };
    mutable boost::mutex mutex;
};
```

Now, `runTests` can be extended to keep timings of all tasks as well as those of the actions/pool shutdown:

```
struct ThreadPoolTest {
    boost::int_least64_t getRunningTimeInMS() const { return relative(Clock::now(), start); }

    template <typename FunctorType, typename ScenarioAction>
    void runTest(ScenarioAction action, bool shouldFunctor1BeCalled, bool shouldFunctor2BeCalled) {
        struct Task {
            std::string name;
            Task(std::string name) : name(name) {}

            FunctorType functor;
            Functor::State before, after, final_;
        } tasks[] = { {"functor1"}, {"functor2"} };

        TP before_action, after_action, pool_final;

        {
            ThreadPool pool(1);
            for (auto& task : tasks) pool.post(std::ref(task.functor));

            for (auto& task : tasks) task.before = task.functor.sample();

            before_action = Clock::now();
            action(pool);
            after_action = Clock::now();

            for (auto& task : tasks) task.after = task.functor.sample();
        }

        pool_final = Clock::now();
        for (auto& task : tasks) task.final_ = task.functor.sample();

        // aids in pretty printing
        for (auto& task : tasks) for (auto sample : { &Task::before, &Task::after, &Task::final_ }) {
            (task.*sample).start = start;
        }

        for (auto& task : tasks)
            std::cout << "DEBUG: " << task.name << " before:" << task.before << " after:" << task.after << " final:" << task.final_ << "\n";
        std::cout << "DEBUG: pool/action before:" << relative(before_action, start) << " after:" << relative(after_action, start) << " final:" << relative(pool_final, start) << "\n";

        check(std::equal_to<>{}, shouldFunctor1BeCalled, is_set(tasks[0].final_.completion), "functor 1 call");
        check(std::equal_to<>{}, shouldFunctor2BeCalled, is_set(tasks[1].final_.completion), "functor 2 call");
    }

  private:
    TP start = Clock::now();
};
```

And our GCC run prints:

```
checkWorkCanBeCancelled
DEBUG: functor1 before:[-1,-1] after:[-1,-1] final:[0,200]
DEBUG: functor2 before:[-1,-1] after:[-1,-1] final:[-1,-1]
DEBUG: pool/action before:0 after:0 final:200
    Error: functor 1 call expected: false actual: true
    passed (functor 2 call).
    Error: running time expected: 150 actual: 200
```

It shows that the action function (`cancel` in this case) got invoked at the same time that our service thread was invoking `functor1`. And `functor2` was never invoked.

**<kbd>[On MSVC](http://rextester.com/ASCJO53404)</kbd>**, the same test prints:

```
checkWorkCanBeCancelled
DEBUG: functor1 before:[-1,-1] after:[-1,-1] final:[2,198]
DEBUG: functor2 before:[-1,-1] after:[-1,-1] final:[198,401]
DEBUG: pool/action before:0 after:0 final:404
    Error: functor 1 call expected: false actual: true
    Error: functor 2 call expected: false actual: true
    Error: running time expected: 150 actual: 405
```

Like with GCC, the `cancel` action ran at time 0ms, but strangely both tasks completed even though they got invoked *after* that action ran.

> This indicates that on Windows, Asio will not prevent existing tasks being dispatched to threads if `io_service::stop()` is invoked. Increasing the load to 9 tasks shows consistent results:
>
> ```
> DEBUG: functor1 before:[-1,-1] after:[-1,-1] final:[2,195]
> DEBUG: functor2 before:[-1,-1] after:[-1,-1] final:[195,398]
> DEBUG: functor3 before:[-1,-1] after:[-1,-1] final:[399,602]
> DEBUG: functor4 before:[-1,-1] after:[-1,-1] final:[602,821]
> DEBUG: functor5 before:[-1,-1] after:[-1,-1] final:[821,1024]
> DEBUG: functor6 before:[-1,-1] after:[-1,-1] final:[1024,1228]
> DEBUG: functor7 before:[-1,-1] after:[-1,-1] final:[1228,1431]
> DEBUG: functor8 before:[-1,-1] after:[-1,-1] final:[1431,1634]
> DEBUG: functor9 before:[-1,-1] after:[-1,-1] final:[1634,1837]
> DEBUG: pool/action before:0 after:0 final:1838
> ```

### Interrupt

Interruptions work fine on **<kbd>[Linux/GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/68ab6b5f86bee9f2)</kbd>** and **<kbd>[MSVC](http://rextester.com/FPIQR62671)</kbd>**.

### Uninterruptables

The last scenario is effectively identical to the second (because the tasks are immune to interruption).

### Summary:

On windows, the behaviour of `io_service::stop()` contradicts the documentation, so that would be a bug:

[image]

Here's a much simpler reproducer:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service s;

    s.post([] { std::this_thread::sleep_for(5ms); std::cout << "1\n"; });
    s.post([] { std::this_thread::sleep_for(5ms); std::cout << "2\n"; });
    s.post([] { std::this_thread::sleep_for(5ms); std::cout << "3\n"; });

    std::thread th([&] { s.run(); });

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1ms);
    s.stop();

    th.join();
}
```

Which prints `1` on GCC and `1 2 3` on MSVC.

Comment: wow, what a great answer. Thank you very much for your investigation and explanation. I will close the current bug I reported to boost and open a new one with your reproducer code.

Comment: Please find the bug on the boost issue tracker here: [#13337](https://svn.boost.org/trac10/ticket/13337)